# Importing a file in a multi-level directory structure

Tags: python, import

I would like to do the following import:

```
from . import foo.bar.foobar
```

Why is that a problem for python? Alternatively

```
from .foo.bar import foobar
```

does not work either.

The foobar module should be imported from the example.py file as seen in this folder structure:

```
test/
|____foo/
|    |____bar/
|         |___ __init__.py
|         |___ foobar.py
|
|____core/
     |____ example.py
```

What works is

```
sys.path.insert(0, r"../foo/bar")
import foobar
```

but i wondered if there was another way.

Comment: Please share your code structure.

Comment: try `from ..foo...`

Comment: can you share the error you  are getting and the directory structure. add `__init__.py` in the directory also to make it work

Comment: Please clarify your folder structure and where are you trying to import the module. Which is your current directory? are trying to import from an installed package?

Comment: The error for the first methode is `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.
The error for the second method is `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.
This is not an installed package, but a local repo.

Comment: @tartearth Is `example.py` the main script that is being run? If so, relative imports using `.` or `..` will never work - they only work when the file is itself being imported as a module. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132912/6445069)

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation in your case is to stick to absolute import path in example:
`from foo.bar import foobar`

Then suppose you are in the `test` folder, you can run your `example.py` file with the below command:
`python -m core.example`

This allow you program to know that it should consider the current folder as the source and then the import will work.

Another way out could be to just move `example.py` directly in `test` and everything would work fine but it probably don't suit your case.